# enable HSP/HFP on LMDE 2 with Dell Wireless 380

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, lmde

I am using LMDE 2 on my Dell Latitude e6430. I want to use a Bluetooth headset for voice calls but my Plantronics Voyager 5200 connects only as an A2DP device.

How can I enable HSP/HFP profiles on my headset?

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:648b Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:8197 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `hciconfig -a hci0`:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 20:16:D8:92:F5:59  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:36654 acl:158 sco:0 events:1968 errors:0
    TX bytes:1962710 acl:2439 sco:0 commands:470 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'mint-latitude-e6430'
    Class: 0x0c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```